# How can I tell what version of apache I'm running?

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, version

I know about the `phpinfo()` way but is there any other way? I'm using CentOS and I can't find the `httpd` executable to run `httpd -v`.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Either `rpm -q httpd` or `/usr/sbin/httpd -v` should work.

Comment: Thanks! I kept looking in /sbin instead of /usr/sbin but both of those worked! Hopefully Google will index this answer instead of the garbage that is out there.

Comment: @tooshel: You could have tried locate.  "locate bin/httpd".  Assuming it's installed, not sure it's standard on CentOS.

Comment: Yeah, we do have locate . . . I found out because another colleague was convinced I didn't move something because the "locate" index was not updated. I still always forget it's there! Thanks!

Comment: Can confirm this works on Mac OS El Capitan.

Comment: This does not work. It only figures out the apache version on the harddisk. Not the currently running one.

Comment: @Peter that may be true but the Apache httpd in Centos restarts the daemon when you update the package so it shouldn’t differ.

Answer (score 79):

For recent Apache versions, try this:

```
$ /usr/sbin/apache2 -v
```

The output should be something like this:

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Jul 24 2015 17:25:11
```

Comment: This worked on GNU/Linux 9 (stretch). Thanks !

Comment: Works ™ for Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS.

Comment: I can confirm it works on `Debian GNU/Linux 8.11 (jessie)`

Answer (score 8):

Run this command in your console:

```
apache2 -v
```

Output should be something like:

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Jan 14 2016 17:45:23
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use:

```
sudo httpd -v
```

The result will look like this :

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.5 (CentOS)
Server built:   Aug  2 2019 10:41:15
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. Your answer seems rather similar to what @jsbillings proposed; would you mind to add some explanation on where your approach differs or what new aspect it tackles?

Answer (score 5):

The above check only includes the primary version number, not including the extended backport patches.

If you installed with yum you can:

```
yum list httpd
```

and get the full version (note the -31 / -47)

`Installed Packages
httpd.x86_64                                                 2.2.15-31.el6.centos
Available Packages
httpd.x86_64                                                 2.2.15-47.el6.centos`

Answer (score 1):

for ports users:

```
port list apache2
apache2                        @2.4.28         www/apache2
```